# Batch prints with set /a

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

Since batch doesn't really have ints, I have to work around it with set /a. Here I have a code segment (from a batch) that evaluates a numeric expression and sets it into a string:

```
@echo off
set test=|set /a 12-10
pause
```

My problem is that this actually prints the "test" string. This is quite inconvenient because I may need to change the string later. Is there any way around this (besides a whole bunch of cls)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe

```
set /a test=12-10 > NUL
```

is what you're after - your version doesn't set `test` at all.

```
C:\temp>type t.cmd
@echo off
set /a test=1+5-21 > NUL
echo Test is: %test%

C:\temp>t.cmd
Test is: -15
```

You can even do indirect assignments like that:

```
C:\temp>type t.cmd
@echo off
setlocal
echo before: %mything%
set var=mything
set /a %var%=4+3
echo after: %mything%


C:\temp>t.cmd
before:
after: 7
```

Comment: I guess I lost sight of my goal. I'm trying to perform an arithmetic operation and set the value to a string. Any tips?

Comment: Please explain that better, it makes no sense. As you said, there are no ints in batch files, so after the snippet I wrote, `test` contains the string `2`. "Set the value to a string" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: The problem with your code is that it still prints 2. I am trying to perform an arithmetic operation (12-10), and then save the result into a string so I can use the string later in the batch file.

Comment: It doesn't (on Win7 anyway). And you can't "save to a string", that doesn't make sense. You can save in a variable. Are you trying to save in a variable whose name you have in a string or something?

Comment: Thank you! My problem was that I was not initializing test within the set /a, which is what you said in the first place. I'm sorry for taking more of your time.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you some ideas:

```
@echo off
set test=|set /a 16-10
ECHO.
SET /A y=12 - 10
ECHO.y = '%y%'
pause>nul
```

Comment: That's not the problem. Notice how your version will print 6 at the beginning. I'm trying to get it not to print the result of the sets.

Comment: Well, it is pretty obvious from my example code, that if there is part of this you don't want to print, then you can change the code so it doesn't print it.  I show an example of using nul  and also and example of using ECHO.  What else would you need?

Comment: The set line still prints. Another Overflower pointed out that it's because the value of the 'set /a' is not being set to anything, it prints to the command line.

Comment: I don't see the set line printing.  Can you tell use what version of the command shell that your DOS box reports that it is?  Mine is 5.1.2600 .